# MYSQL SELECT statement using DATETIME with no time

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, datetime

This works perfectly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customers 
FROM customertable 
WHERE time_paid BETWEEN '2016-06-28 10:27:55' AND '2016-07-05 14:07:51';
```

However, since I'm using javascript datepicker for the user to pick the date periods and have only dates but no times this apparently does not work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customers 
FROM customertable 
WHERE time_paid BETWEEN '2016-06-28' AND '2016-07-05';
```

My select statement is this: `$t1` is lower date while `$t2` is upper date.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT customertable FROM customer WHERE time_paid BETWEEN '$t1' AND '$t2'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Is there a way I can insert a concatenated date, say `'$t1'.12.00.00`, on my select statement to take care of the full `DATETIME` entry on my database when selecting?

Comment: `where date(time_paid) between ...`, then.

Comment: Yeh, you can do `$t1 = $t1 . ' 00:00:00'; $t2 = $t2 . ' 23:59:59';` Goes from start of day 1 to end of day 2. NOTE - A space is required after the concatenation

Answer (score 1):

use mysql function date add

```
mysql> SELECT '2008-01-02';
+------------+
| 2008-01-02 |
+------------+
| 2008-01-02 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT ADDDATE('2008-01-02', INTERVAL 0 HOUR);
+----------------------------------------+
| ADDDATE('2008-01-02', INTERVAL 0 HOUR) |
+----------------------------------------+
| 2008-01-02 00:00:00                    |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


SELECT DISTINCT customertable FROM customer WHERE time_paid BETWEEN ADDDATE('$t1',INTERVAL 0 HOUR) AND ADDDATE('$t2',INTERVAL '23:59' HOUR_MINUTE)";
```